# Google Calendar event created at a wrong date and time

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone, google-calendar-api

### .createEvent() doesn't work properly

When I executed the following code, an event was created at the wrong date and time. I wanted to create an event on **2021/2/21 17:00 - 22:00**, but the event was created on **2021/2/22 7:00 - 12:00**.
Here are my GAS code and a screenshot of my Google Calendar.

```
function pracCalendar() {
  const id = 'foo@gmail.com';
  const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);

  const title = 'Test Event';
  const startTime = new Date('2021/2/21 17:00');
  const endTime = new Date('2021/2/21 22:00');
  const options = {
    description: 'Test Description',
    location: 'Test Location',
    guests: 'bar@gmail.com',
    sendInvites: true
  }

  calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options);
}
```

[image: Google Calendar]

---

### Is this caused by timezone?

I'm not sure if it's related but just in case... I currently live in Japan. My Google Calendar's timezone is `Asia/Tokyo`.

Could anyone tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible Issue:

I think the issue has to do with the **different** timezone between the Google Apps Script project and your calendar.

To check that, please add to your current script the following two lines:

```
  console.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone()) // script timezone
  console.log(CalendarApp.getTimeZone()) // calendar timezone
```

### Solution:

If there is a discrepancy between the two timezones, update the timezone of the Google Apps Script project. You need to open the `appsscript.json` file and adjust the timezone to match exactly the timezone of your calendar.

Here you can find the instructions on how to open the `appsscript.json` file:

- [Editing a manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest)

after you unhide it, it will be visible in the script editor. For example, you need to change `Europe/Paris` from:

```
"timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
```

to what `CalendarApp.getTimeZone()` returns (most likely `Asia/Tokyo`) and save the changes.

**Please Note:**

Besides the 2 hours difference, your code should create an event for the 21st of February (2021/2/21) but the resulting event (in your screenshot) is created on 22nd. Be careful with this.